# Asp.Net Application keeps on restarting so the cache is big

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, caching

I have an Asp.net application hosted on a shared server.

I have few cache objects. One cache object contains around 1 million records with three columns. The rest of the cache objects contain a few hundred records only.

All the records are static. These records are never going to be changed and will be shown in auto complete ajax calls.

I am using Sql Server 2008 for storing data.

If I set the following:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

The Application is started more occasionally than if i set it to TRUE

My Code:

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Global.CacheInfo += "Started on" + "----" + DateTime.Now + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine; ;


        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

        using (BEntity context = new BEntity())
        {
            // Adding Items to Cache
            BLSuggestion.GetAllTitle();
            BLSuggestion.GetAllSubCategories();

        }

        PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Applications", "Cache % Machine Memory Limit Used", "__TOTAL__", true);
        Global.CacheInfo += string.Format("{0:0.00}%", pc.NextValue());

    }
```

This value comes to be around 95% if the application is started. Later a few more cache objects are created. But even then the Application is restarted after about 1 minute.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the code look like that populates your cache (GetAllTitle and GetAllSubCategories)? If this cache is consuming all your memory, it's very possible there's a more memory conservative way to cache the data in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS automatically restarts the application when certain (user defined) CPU/memory thresholds are reached. Since you are storing lots of info in memory I guess that you have reached this threshold and IIS simply takes down the AppDomain as instructed in the configuration to prevent your application eating lots of memory. This is often done by shared hosting providers. So you could ask your provider what are those limits that your application is configured to run under.

Comment: Can we programatically find out what is the current limit example before cache what is the limit and after cache what is the limit

Comment: The limit is configured in IIS. You can find it out programatically using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` but you will need administrator privileges on the server which I doubt you have because you mentioned something about shared hosting. So simply contact your provider.

Comment: SO Cache % Machine Memory Limit Used does not have any role right? What i find out is without caching it is about 90% and with caching it is around 90-95%. SO everything is dependent upon CPU/memory.

Comment: In the IIS administration console you could configure both CPU and memory thresholds.

Comment: Can you specify some alternative for caching? Will Application object solves the issue??

Comment: The simple solution is to increase this limit.  This entire problem seems because he is using shared hosting.

Comment: No, Application won't solve the problem. It will even make it worse because when you store inside the Cache you could define expiration policy, whereas if you store in the Application object it is persisted *forever* (until you manually remove it or IIS simply decides to recycle the application pool because you have ran out of memory). So the way I see it is that you have 2 possibilities: either you talk with your hosting provider to increase the limit or don't store such a large volume of data in memory. By the way there are other distributed Cache providers which could be used

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for the valuable suggestions.